# How to execute a piece of code in a python function after the caller has finished executing?

Tags: python, function, functional-programming, yield

I have a situation which can be simplified like this:

```py
def caller(func):
    print('''
            This is the caller function.
            After completing execution of this function, do the JOB(see below)
            ''')
    print(*func())

def my_func():
    for i in range(5):
        yield i

    # JOB:
    print('''
            This text needs to be printed
            after everything from the caller function
            (text and numbers both) is printed
            ''')

caller(my_func)
```

What it prints:

> ```
>         This is the caller function.
>         After completing execution of this function, do the JOB(see below)
>         
>
>         This text needs to be printed
>         after everything from the caller function
>         (text and numbers both) is printed
>
>          0 1 2 3 4
> ```

What I want:

> ```
>         This is the caller function.
>         After completing execution of this function, do the JOB(see below)
>
>         0 1 2 3 4   
>
>         This text needs to be printed
>         after everything from the caller function
>         (text and numbers both) is printed
> ```

In theory, I could put the JOB in a new function and call that function after the caller is done executing. But I need the variables that I created in `my_func`. Also, it would make my code messier.

Comment: What is the purpose of yield in my_func? `*func()` will consume the generator and get a list produced by yield, and the job will be done before print function begins to handle the parameter. So, I can not see the meaning of yield in your my_func here.

Comment: In reality, I have an object whose state I want to return at the position of yield statement. In the JOB section, I am modifying the state of the object. Hence I cannot have a `return` after the JOB is done, because it would return the state of the object finally and not as it was at the position of `yield` statement. Any ideas other than your answer?

Comment: Sorry, don't have good ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `*func()` in `print(*func())` will firstly consume the generator `func()`, which will produce a list `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` and get the `JOB` done.

That is to say, with form of `print(*func())`, the `JOB` in `func` must be done before the `print` function begins to execute its body code.

So, in my option, you should do what you say: put the JOB in a new function.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute: print(i, end=" ") instead of yield i